# Iterating over a mongodb cursor serially (waiting for callbacks before moving to next document)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoskin, async.js

Using mongoskin, I can do a query like this, which will return a cursor:

```
myCollection.find({}, function(err, resultCursor) {
      resultCursor.each(function(err, result) {

      }
}
```

However, I'd like to call some async functions for each document, and only move on to the next item on the cursor after this has called back (similar to the eachSeries structure in the async.js module).  E.g:

```
myCollection.find({}, function(err, resultCursor) {
      resultCursor.each(function(err, result) {

            externalAsyncFunction(result, function(err) {
               //externalAsyncFunction completed - now want to move to next doc
            });

      }
}
```

How could I do this?

Thanks

**UPDATE:**

I don't wan't to use `toArray()` as this is a large batch operation, and the results might not fit in memory in one go.

Comment: If you're blocking and waiting for the async function to complete before moving on, what's the point of calling it asynchronously?

Comment: @RotemHermon I don't have any choice! It's not my function and it's async. (Will rename myAsyncFunction to externalAsyncFunction...)

Comment: Why are you not using `toArray()` and then a recursive function to iterate over the result?

Comment: @Салман - good question - I'm not using toArray as it's a large batch operation and the full result might not fit in memory. (I'll update question)

Answer (score 49, accepted):

If you don't want to load all of the results into memory using toArray, you can iterate using the cursor with something like the following.

```
myCollection.find({}, function(err, resultCursor) {
  function processItem(err, item) {
    if(item === null) {
      return; // All done!
    }

    externalAsyncFunction(item, function(err) {
      resultCursor.nextObject(processItem);
    });

  }

  resultCursor.nextObject(processItem);
}
```

Comment: This method didn't work for me for large dataset. I get "RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded".

Comment: @SoichiHayashi There are a number of things which will cause a RangeError, but the example above shouldn't throw it. Maybe if you provide more details as a separate question I can help you figure out where it is going wrong.

Comment: @SoichiHayashi wrap the async function or callback in a `process.nextTick`!

Comment: @SoichiHayashi to follow up on @zamnuts - the reason your stack is overflowing with the example above is because every time you process an item, you run another callback to process the next item *within the processing function of the current one*. As your resultset grows, you loop through more function calls and each one creates a new stack frame on top of the previous. Wrapping the async callback in `process.nextTick`, `setImmediate` or `setTimeout` causes it to run in the next loop, 'outside' of the call stack we've created to process each document.

Comment: What about `cursor.forEach()`?

Comment: @Redsandro - cursor.forEach() provides no async way of signalling to move to next item.

Comment: for clarity I think adding the `externalAsyncFunction` example would help. I didn't understand at first.
        `function externalAsyncFunction(doc, next) {
            // process here
            next();
        }`

Comment: @Lex That is the example function used in the original question. It makes more sense when you start there and then read the answer!

Comment: callstack over flow and process.nextTick should be avoided.

Answer (score 95):

A more modern approach that uses `async`/`await`:

```
const cursor = db.collection("foo").find({});
while(await cursor.hasNext()) {
  const doc = await cursor.next();
  // process doc here
}
```

**Notes:**

- This may be *even more* simple to do when [async iterators](https://jakearchibald.com/2017/async-iterators-and-generators/) arrive.
- You'll probably want to add try/catch for error checking.
- The containing function should be `async` or the code should be wrapped in `(async function() { ... })()` since it uses `await`.
- If you want, add `await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 1000));` (pause for 1 second) at the end of the while loop to show that it does process docs one after the other.

Comment: Worked perfectly, thank you. Any idea if there are any pitfalls with large datasets?

Comment: great, this is the best solution, unlike the chosen one that will just crash

Comment: How do you use this in node? I get this error: "SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier" at the "cursor.hasNext()"

Comment: @Nico, Sorry for the late reply, but see point number 3 in the notes ;)

Answer (score 39):

[since node.js v10.3](https://node.green/#ES2018-features-Asynchronous-Iterators) you can use async iterator

```js
const cursor = db.collection('foo').find({});
for await (const doc of cursor) {
  // do your thing
  // you can even use `await myAsyncOperation()` here
}
```

Jake Archibald wrote [a great blog post](https://jakearchibald.com/2017/async-iterators-and-generators/) about async iterators, that I came to know after reading @user993683's answer.

Comment: Was looking for this solution, thanks!

Answer (score 11):

This works with large dataset by using setImmediate:

```
var cursor = collection.find({filter...}).cursor();

cursor.nextObject(function fn(err, item) {
    if (err || !item) return;

    setImmediate(fnAction, item, arg1, arg2, function() {
        cursor.nextObject(fn);
    });
});

function fnAction(item, arg1, arg2, callback) {
    // Here you can do whatever you want to do with your item.
    return callback();
}
```

Comment: This is great, but you don't need the ".cursor()" on the first line (I got an error).

Comment: It depends on the version of mongoose used. It was for an older one

Answer (score 4):

If someone is looking for a Promise way of doing this (as opposed to using callbacks of nextObject), here it is. I am using Node v4.2.2 and mongo driver v2.1.7. This is kind of an asyncSeries version of `Cursor.forEach()`:

```
function forEachSeries(cursor, iterator) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    var count = 0;
    function processDoc(doc) {
      if (doc != null) {
        count++;
        return iterator(doc).then(function() {
          return cursor.next().then(processDoc);
        });
      } else {
        resolve(count);
      }
    }
    cursor.next().then(processDoc);
  });
}
```

To use this, pass the cursor and an iterator that operates on each document asynchronously (like you would for Cursor.forEach). The iterator needs to return a promise, like most mongodb native driver functions do.

Say, you want to update all documents in the collection `test`. This is how you would do it:

```
var theDb;
MongoClient.connect(dbUrl).then(function(db) {
  theDb = db;     // save it, we'll need to close the connection when done.
  var cur = db.collection('test').find();

  return forEachSeries(cur, function(doc) {    // this is the iterator
    return db.collection('test').updateOne(
      {_id: doc._id},
      {$set: {updated: true}}       // or whatever else you need to change
    );
    // updateOne returns a promise, if not supplied a callback. Just return it.
  });
})
.then(function(count) {
  console.log("All Done. Processed", count, "records");
  theDb.close();
})
```

Comment: I don't see where `forEachSeries` is being called.

Comment: call stack overflow.

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this using the async lib. The key point here is to check if the current doc is null. If it is, it means you are finished.

```
async.series([
        function (cb) {
            cursor.each(function (err, doc) {
                if (err) {
                    cb(err);
                } else if (doc === null) {
                    cb();
                } else {
                    console.log(doc);
                    array.push(doc);
                }
            });
        }
    ], function (err) {
        callback(err, array);
    });
```

Comment: Hi Antoine - the problem I had with this approach is that if you need to do something for each record asyncronously, then there's no way for the cursor loop to wait until that's done.  (The cursor.each doesn't provide a 'next' callback, so only sync operations are possible within it).

Answer (score 0):

You can get the result in an `Array` and iterate using a recursive function, something like this.

```
myCollection.find({}).toArray(function (err, items) {
    var count = items.length;
    var fn = function () {
        externalAsyncFuntion(items[count], function () {
            count -= 1;
            if (count) fn();
        })
    }

    fn();
});
```

**Edit:**

This is only applicable for small datasets, for larger one's you should use cursors as mentioned in other answers.

Comment: Sorry, I was too slow to answer your question in the comments - I can't use toArray as the result set is too big.

Comment: Oh ok. Then the other answer is suitable for you.

Comment: While true, it's better to avoid this pattern as it can break as data grows.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a Future:

```
myCollection.find({}, function(err, resultCursor) {
    resultCursor.count(Meteor.bindEnvironment(function(err,count){
        for(var i=0;i<count;i++)
        {
            var itemFuture=new Future();

            resultCursor.nextObject(function(err,item)){
                itemFuture.result(item);
            }

            var item=itemFuture.wait();
            //do what you want with the item, 
            //and continue with the loop if so

        }
    }));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

A more modern approach that uses `for await`:

```
const cursor = db.collection("foo").find({});

for await(const doc of cursor) {
  // process doc here with await
  await processDoc(doc);
}
```

Answer (score -2):

You could use simple setTimeOut's. This is an example in typescript running on nodejs (I am using promises via the 'when' module but it can be done without them as well):

```
        import mongodb = require("mongodb");

        var dbServer = new mongodb.Server('localhost', 27017, {auto_reconnect: true}, {});
        var db =  new mongodb.Db('myDb', dbServer);

        var util = require('util');
        var when = require('when'); //npm install when

        var dbDefer = when.defer();
        db.open(function() {
            console.log('db opened...');
            dbDefer.resolve(db);
        });

        dbDefer.promise.then(function(db : mongodb.Db){
            db.collection('myCollection', function (error, dataCol){
                if(error) {
                    console.error(error); return;
                }

                var doneReading = when.defer();

                var processOneRecordAsync = function(record) : When.Promise{
                    var result = when.defer();

                    setTimeout (function() {
                        //simulate a variable-length operation
                        console.log(util.inspect(record));
                        result.resolve('record processed');
                    }, Math.random()*5);

                    return result.promise;
                }

                var runCursor = function (cursor : MongoCursor){
                    cursor.next(function(error : any, record : any){
                        if (error){
                            console.log('an error occurred: ' + error);
                            return;
                        }
                        if (record){
                            processOneRecordAsync(record).then(function(r){
                                setTimeout(function() {runCursor(cursor)}, 1);
                            });
                        }
                        else{
                            //cursor up
                            doneReading.resolve('done reading data.');
                        }
                    });
                }

                dataCol.find({}, function(error, cursor : MongoCursor){
                    if (!error)
                    {
                        setTimeout(function() {runCursor(cursor)}, 1);
                    }
                });

                doneReading.promise.then(function(message : string){
                    //message='done reading data'
                    console.log(message);
                });
            });
        });
```